# Gradle build error: Failed to resolve:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just downloaded Android Studio and created a new project and I'm getting gradle build errors:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso-core:2.2.2

and

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.appcompat-v7:25.3.1

**This error was resolved reinstalling the SDK Tools + Repository + API when launching android studio as admin.**

I've installed API Level 25 which what I want to build on and have downloaded the SDK Build-Tools. I have also already download the support repository

Here's my app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jtsalas.mirrorcontrol"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try to set minSdkVersion lower then targetSdkVersion.

Comment: Change minSdkVersion to 24 and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you post the `buildscript` section of your gradle build so we can see the repository configuration and android gradle build plugin version?

Comment: see the below [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417743/3805770) it will give you the reason for why to include maven url.

Comment: espresso always had transitive dependency issues so I think you need to exclude something but I am not sure what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SDK manager, make sure you have both the Android Support Repository and Google Repository installed and up to date.  You should then be able to find the relevant artifacts in sub folders of your /extras/android/m2repository directory

Comment: This is what my /extras/android/m2repository directory looks like: http://imgur.com/a/WbH2Q I have the latest versions of the Support Repository (47.0.0) and Google Repository (51)

Comment: @JavierSalas do you have aar and jar files in /extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1 and in /extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/test/espresso/espresso-core/2.2.2 ?

Comment: I also noticed a gradle syntax that I'm not familiar with in your question, you can try this for defining your espresso dependency instead: `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }`

Comment: I don't have those files. Do we have the same SDK Platforms? http://i.imgur.com/WvgD4VE.png Here's my SDK tools as well http://i.imgur.com/kuFh2J6.png. I have also added the buildscript to the main question

Comment: If you don't have those directories, you may have a permissions problem that prevents their download and installation.  There should be many files and directories in the m2repository

Comment: So I restarted android studio as admin and reinstalled SDK Platform API Level 25 and the build tools and Support Repository and was able to get rid of the: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.appcompat-v7:25.3.1 error. However I still have the Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso-core:2.2.2 error

Answer (score 2):

From your error it seems that you are not including espresso libraries. The solution to this is adding espresso core library which is part Android Testing support library which is hosted in the google's Maven repository think this as kind of git repository but for dependencies.

So we tell the gradle build system to look in the Maven repository for dependencies by specifying its URL.

This is done by adding Maven url in the application level build.gradle file under repositories block

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

and in the module level build.gradle file mention the dependencies that you want from the maven repository by mention their name as follows:

```
dependencies{
//other dependencies go here

//testing dependencies
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

That is the reason for including Maven repository url in the app level build.gradle file, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In project.gradle file, the **allprojects** root align this way:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
```

**jitpack** is used as the dependency for multiple libraries, if you're not using any sort of library that don't requires it then not include maven line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know the perfect answer but..... how about comparing with my SDK Tools?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I have v25.0.1 and v25.0.3 of android sdk build tools both installed. All of the other check boxes are marked.

Comment: I can't remember the exact day, but I was in trouble like you. I re-installed java 1st, deleted and reseted environment variable (Windows 7). In my problem, it worked. (At that time, I forgot to download java. LOL)

Comment: v25.0.3 is a newer version of the build tools

Comment: I'll try uninstalling and reinstall java will report back

Comment: But I think gradle document isn't different from mine :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uninstalling Android Studios and deleting old versions of Android Studios in my  C:\Users[Username] and reinstalled Android Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you updated android studio  and opening previous project in it.The simplest way is create new project and copy 
1. compileSdkVersion 26
2. buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
3. targetSdkVersion 26
4. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
 and paste them in appropriate places in app level build gradle.
it will ask to update to take advantages .. allow it to update. 
best luck ... It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

if your project is Flutter,

1. clean project  [by 'flutter clean' command]
2. In project.gradle file add [ google() ]
3. in Android studio: File Menu  -> Invalidate...

project.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
   }
}
```