# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My build.gradle file is below:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.xavier.hello"

    minSdkVersion 15

    targetSdkVersion 26

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }

}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
```

{

exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

```
})

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

It gives following error every time:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the 'repositories' blocks of your gradle files?

Comment: See my answer from other stackoverflow post it will give you the reason for why to include maven url [failed to resolve dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417743/3805770)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I wanted to try Espresso.

I've resolved it by adding

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

to

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the same thing. Apparently, Maven is one of the most important things to get it running. But, I don't know the reason behind it.

Comment: @XavierGonsalves check the below answer for clarification

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by two different issues:

1. A problem with your gradle file(s).
2. Internet connectivity issues.

The problem in my case was Internet connectivity. I actually was connected to the Internet when trying to build my project, but I had a very slow connection. Once I had solid wifi, I ran the build again and this issue went away. You also may need to adjust your settings for running online/offline, as Android Studio will tell you. In your project’s build.gradle file you should have this maven reference in your repositories:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google() //you may or may not need this line
}
```